# More Information on org.hyperledger.composer.system.*** as a Resource in permisions.acl file. Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to write very detailed permissions.acl file for an application. But I am unable to provide proper "org.hyperledger.composer.system.****" Resource access as I am unable to find their documentation. I found this link 
in the documentation but it is not helpful cause the description part of the page is very wierd.

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/systemns/01_summary.html

For Example,

```
        Namespace                              Name              Description
org.hyperledger.composer.system.Transaction | Transaction | A transaction named Transaction
```

This doesn't make sense and I know what its called I am wondering what does it do. The entire page has such descriptions.

Let me know if there is a more detailed place which can explain all "org.hyperledger.composer.system.****" used in Resources(permissions).

I have also raised it as an issue here
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4680

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found It

Summary
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/systemns/01_summary.html

Assets
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/systemns/02_assets

Participants
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/systemns/03_participants

Transactions
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/systemns/04_transactions

Event
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/systemns/05_events

Enum
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/systemns/06_enums